# jQuery modal and asp.net button click

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have read some solutions to this issue but all of them are using a dialog and not a modal, plus none of the solutions I have tried work yet. The issue is I can't get my asp button click to fire inside of a jquery modal. here is the code:

```js
$(function () {

    $('.showmodal-login').click(function (e) {
       // e.preventDefault();
        ShowLoginForm($(this).attr('href'));

        return false;
    });

    $('#<%= btnClose.ClientID %>').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (isMobile) {
            $('.modal-content').each(function () {
                if ($(this).is(':visible')) {
                    $(this).toggle();
                }
            });
            $("#main").toggle();
        }
        else {
            $.modal.close();
        }
        return false;
    });

});
```

```js
function ShowLoginForm(redirectUrl) {
    if (isMobile) {
        $("#modal-login").toggle();
        $("#main").toggle();
        $('#login-form').show();
        $('#login-message').hide();
       // $('#<%= btnSubmit.ClientID %>').attr('data-redirecturl', redirectUrl);
    }
    else {
        $("#modal-login").modal({
            maxWidth: 338,
            autoResize: false,
            close: false,
            onShow: function (dlg) {
                $('#login-form').show();
                $('#login-message').hide();
                //$('#<%= btnSubmit.ClientID %>').attr('data-redirecturl', redirectUrl);
                ResizeModal();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

### html

```
 <div id="modal-login" class="modal-content">

<div id="login-form">
    <div class="content-wrap">

        <p>Login with your username and password to access the selected link.</p>
        <asp:Label ID="lblUsername" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="txtUsername">Username:</asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtUsername" runat="server" Width="268px" ClientIDMode="Static" />
        <asp:Label ID="lblPassword" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="txtPassword">Password:</asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtPassword" runat="server" Width="268px" ClientIDMode="Static" TextMode="Password" />
    </div>
    <div id="btnSub" class="buttons">
        <asp:HyperLink ID="hlnkCancel" runat="server" NavigateUrl="#" CssClass="close-modal">Cancel</asp:HyperLink>
        <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Login" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" />
    </div>
</div>
<div id="login-message">
    <div class="content-wrap">
    </div>
    <div class="buttons">
        <asp:Button ID="btnClose" runat="server" Text="Close" />
    </div>
</div>
```

I have solved this in the past with the jquery dialog by adding

```
 function reLoad() {
    // jQuery.post();
    document.forms["frmMain"].submit();
}
```

but that didn't work in this case.

Comment: Are you sure that `name=frmMain` for this modal form?

Comment: Yeah I made sure of that, I just did ome digging and found out it is using jquery.simplemodal.1.4.2.js . It appends the modal outside of form tags....

Comment: @SamCromer have you found a solution to your problem?

Comment: Yes I did. I had add appendTo: "form"; SimpleModal.js places the div outside of the form tags.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing UseSubmitBehavior="false" in your asp button. Add this like..

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Login" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" UseSubmitBehavior="false" />
```

I had the same issue. Mine would only work with Link Buttons because it doesn't use a submit behavior. The buttons do so you must turn it off. This should work.